# Calling a webservice from a mapped drive?

Tags: c#, web-services, mapped-drive

I have created a webservice which also has a client (console app). This client is placed on a mapped drive. Calling the service results in an error with the log4net dll. The error is a ThrowSecurityException and the message it has is something like this (I only have the German text, so I have to translate): *The assembly only allows callers which are fully trustworthy.*

The dll is in the same directory as the client exe file. I tested on a normal drive and it works fine. Ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

try to give the dll read permission to everyone http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx
you might need to do it from the original location.
try to change the securityPolicy section in your config file to this:

```
<system.web>
  <securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Minimal" policyFile="web_minimaltrust.config"/>
  </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

you can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx

Comment: With original you mean the one running the client on the mapped drive should set it?

Comment: I mean on the computer that physically has the drive - the computer that doing the share

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `FullTrust` to the network drive (it has `LocalIntranet` by default). I think this should be similar as for a network share. See [Using CasPol to Fully Trust a Share](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx).

**Edit:**

Or try something like this:

```
caspol -q -machine -addgroup 1 -url file://X:/* FullTrust -name "X Drive"
```

(replace X with your mapped drive letter)

Comment: Have you tried examining the security policy of the mapped drive and of individual assemblies that you execute? Did the `caspol` command that you ran have any effect on the security policy?